# how to see original and --bind mountpoints

Tags: linux, mount, bind-mount

Lest say I mount a usb drive to /mnt and next I run this...

```
mount --bind /mnt /tmp/test.d
```

It's a successful bind, but now when I run `lsblk` only the bind point shows.

How can I get all bound and original mount points listed?

When I use `findmnt`, it shows both, but it doesn't tell me which one is the original mount point. How can I learn this?

Comment: why not using mount or better findmnt?

Comment: Thats good info. How can I find which is the original mount point? Both show up and have the same information other than mount directory.

Comment: Yeah, `findmnt -R /path/to/mount/point/dir` will make it very clear w/ defaulys.

Comment: Using device instead of directory worked for me. 
findmnt -r /dev/sdb1
this listed all mount and binds :)

Comment: IIRC this information is not kept anywhere: after `mount --bind`, the two copies are equivalent, there isn't one that's more “original” than the other. After all there could be no original if you'd already unmounted `/mnt`.

Comment: Thank you Gilles. You answered my other concern. I was just asking the wrong question :)