# Why can I (or cannot) mount a mounted device again? What is happening?

Tags: mount, devices, block-device

Why can I (or cannot) mount a mounted device again? What is happening?
For example:

```
/tmp/test$ sudo mount /dev/sda5 ./1;echo ${?}
0
/tmp/test$ sudo mount /dev/sda5 ./2;echo ${?}
0
/tmp/test$ sudo mount | grep test
/dev/sda5 on /tmp/test/1 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda5 on /tmp/test/2 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/tmp/test$ sudo umount ./1 ./2;echo ${?}
0
/tmp/test$ sudo losetup
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE          DIO
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /tmp/test/grub.iso   0
/tmp/test$ sudo mount /dev/loop0 ./1;echo ${?}
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
0
/tmp/test$ sudo mount /dev/loop0 ./2;echo ${?}
mount: /dev/loop0 is already mounted or /tmp/test/2 busy
       /dev/loop0 is already mounted on /tmp/test/1
32
/tmp/test$ sudo mount | grep test
/dev/loop0 on /tmp/test/1 type iso9660 (ro,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048)
/tmp/test$
```

Comment: Content of `/etc/fstab` ?

Comment: see my update. @schweik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem this reason is the `-w` and `-r` flag for multiple locations mount need same.

For example(`/dev/sda5` is already mounted with `-o rw`):

```
$ sudo mount -r ./grub.iso ./1;echo $?
0
$ sudo mount -r ./grub.iso ./2;echo $?
0
$ sudo mount -r ./grub.iso ./3;echo $?
0
$ sudo umount ./1 ./2 ./3;echo $?
0
$ sudo mount -r /dev/sda5 /mnt;echo $?
mount: /dev/sda5 is already mounted or /mnt busy
       /dev/sda5 is already mounted on /home/xx/yy
32
```

Also see [man mount for stretch](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/mount/mount.8.en.html):

> ```
> -w, --rw, --read-write
>           Mount the filesystem read/write.  This is the default.  A synonym is -o rw.
> ```

This is(seem) why you can mount `/dev/sda5` on multiple locations with defaults options,but cannot mount `grub.iso` with defaults options on multiple locations

Comment: Nice. If you specify some *other* filesystem options on the second mount, including acl/noacl, I think they end up ignored. Maybe ro/rw are handled differently. https://lwn.net/Articles/762355/  / https://lwn.net/ml/linux-kernel/87d0uqpba5.fsf@xmission.com/

Answer (score 0):

Judging on the evidence: the `/dev/sda2` was originaly mounted as the `/` (file system root). But the fstab was completely disabled and the main mount is done in your `my_init` script file. There the first mount add the complete `/dev/sda2` which contents the original root  file system, the next line mounts to the same `/home/` only `/home/home/` by `--bind` option in ought to hide the rest of the original root filesystem. If you do `umount /home/` once, you should see (as I wrote) the whole original root filesystem in the `/home/` folder, i.e. ls /home/ then gives: `bin boot dev  etc  home ...`

Do not ask me, why somebody did it so.

Comment: You are right,but why I can directly mount a mounted device without `--bind`?

Comment: because with --bind you mount _folder_ not **device**

Comment: A bind mount is analogous to a hard link. They allow to create multiple paths that refer to (portions of) the same filesystem. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346460/147970 for details.

Comment: I'm sorry,but see my example code update @schweik